# Self in protocol

Tags: swift

I am learning swift and playing with Xcode.
and I always dig into the definitions. I have seen that:

```
public protocol GeneratorType {
    typealias Element
    @warn_unused_result
    public mutating func next() -> Self.Element?
}
```

A struct that conforming this protocol:

```
public struct IndexingGenerator<Elements : Indexable> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    public init(_ elements: Elements)
    public mutating func next() -> Elements._Element?
}
```

I know 'Self' means that returning the conforming type. But what does 'Self.Element' mean?
and the function that implemented the requirement that returning 'Elements._Element?', I can’t see 'Elements._Element?' is equal to 'Self.Element?'.
Can anyone explain to me this?
and tell me more about this. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Self.Element` refers to the concrete type that any type implementing `GeneratorType` protocol will declare as its `Element` typealias.

For example, in this generator of Fibonacci numbers:

```
struct Fibonacci: GeneratorType {
    typealias Element = Int

    private var value: Int = 1
    private var previous: Int = 0

    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        let newValue = value + previous

        previous = value
        value = newValue

        return previous
    }
}
```

... you implement `GeneratorType` protocol and indicate what will be its `Element` typealias (`Int` in this case), and that's the type that generator's `next()` will be returning (well, actually the optional of that type).

Quite often, though, you would not have to explicitly specify typealiases when implementing parametrised protocols, as Swift is smart enough to *infer* them for you.  E.g. for the Fibonacci numbers generator from the above example the following will also do:

```
struct Fibonacci: GeneratorType {
    private var value: Int = 1
    private var previous: Int = 0

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        let newValue = value + previous

        previous = value
        value = newValue

        return previous
    }
}
```

... Swift knows from the signature of `next()` that it returns `Int?`, and that `GeneratorType` implementors also must have `next()` in their to-do list, and that these methods must return `Element?` types.  So, Swift just puts 2 and 2 together, and *infers* that `Element?` must be the same thing as `Int?`, and therefore `Element == Int`.

---

About this:

```
public struct IndexingGenerator<Elements : Indexable> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    public init(_ elements: Elements)
    public mutating func next() -> Elements._Element?
}
```

Here we have four things going on:

- We declare *generic* type `IndexingGenerator` that takes a parameter-type called `Elements`.
- This `Elements` type has a constraint that it must implement `Indexable` protocol.
- The generator that we implement is supposed to return values of the type that is accessible via `Indexable` interface of `Elements`, which is known to `IndexingGenerator` via dot-syntax as `Elements._Element`.
- Swift infers that `Element` of `IndexingGenerator` is the same thing as `Elements._Element`.

So, essentially the above delclaration is equivalent to:

```
public struct IndexingGenerator<Elements : Indexable> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    public typealias Element = Elements._Element
    public init(_ elements: Elements)
    public mutating func next() -> Element?
}
```

---

Finally, if curious why `_Element` and not just `Element` like in `GeneratorType`, here is what they write in the [open-source Swift repository](https://github.com/apple/swift) (under swift/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift):

> The declaration of `_Element` and subscript here is a trick used to break a cyclic conformance/deduction that Swift can't handle.  We need something other than a `CollectionType.Generator.Element` that can be used as `IndexingGenerator<T>`'s `Element`.  Here we arrange for the `CollectionType` itself to have an `Element` type that's deducible from its subscript.  Ideally we'd like to constrain this `Element` to be the same as `CollectionType.Generator.Element`, but we have no way of expressing it today.

Comment: that i know, i want to know, the return type Elements._Element? and Self.Element? , how they link together.

Comment: and i think your example is wrong. should be like that, mutating func next() -> Int? I guess.

Comment: Yours is wrong at the first example. The function should return Int? Not Element?

Comment: See the edits.  Both are correct, difference is whether you specify the typealias explicitly or allow Swift to infer the type for you.

Comment: The second I know is correct. But the first one if you tell the compiler explicitly, it should be told the return explicitly, right??

Comment: sorry, this part i don't understand, Swift automatically infers that GeneratorType's typealias Element should be the same type as _Element typealias from Elements. can you explain a bit more? thanks